# LIRC with Raspberry PI , problems

Tags: gpio, python, lirc

I am trying to get my SONY CRS60A IR remote to work with LIRC and raspberry pi 2.
Here is the setup : [image]
That is what my setup looks like.

When I run mode2 -d /dev/lirc0 , I am able to read the pulses. But after running IRRECORD(and copying the generated file to /etc/lirc/lirc.d) , when I try to run IRW , and press any buttons on my remote, I get no output.

I had just randomly done this 1 day back, and it had worked then.

What is the problem ?
IRSEND is able to send light (i can see from a digital camera) , but the device fails to react to it(I have pointed it directly at it, from a distance of 2 inches)

I am willing to 'reinstall' lirc , deleting all the files generated by it(if its possible, tell me how to )

Comment: The image isn't very helpful without proper description.

Comment: The image is really needed. They are just 2 transistors to amplify the current from the photodiode. I just included to give people an idea of what my setup is

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial. http://mvartan.com/2014/11/25/controlling-your-tv-or-any-ir-device-with-raspberry-pi/ You'll need to verify that you have the models running, and that the lirc service is running.